# OutBounds Exception on Filtered ViewList

Tags: listview, javafx, observablelist, jfoenix

im working on a small application that fetches information from a DB and displays it in a ListView , then I select elements of the list and move it to a second list, I must be able to add and remove elements between list. I have also implemented both lists with FilteredLists for search functionality. My code works, Im able to switch elements between lists, but I get an OutOfBounds exception when I try to return elements from the second list to the first one, or when I move the last element of the 1st list to the second one.
Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Thanks in advance.

**The exception**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.get(FilteredList.java:172)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:459)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.lambda$new$160(ListCell.java:167)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.sourceChanged(FilteredList.java:147)
at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList.lambda$getListener$23(TransformationList.java:106)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.removeAll(ObservableListWrapper.java:185)
at com.kalypso.WCExporter.MainController.removeItemFromList(MainController.java:351)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

Lists Declaration

```
@FXML
private JFXListView leftList;

@FXML
private JFXTextField leftFilter;

@FXML
private JFXListView rightList;

@FXML
private JFXTextField rightFilter;
private ObservableList<String> leftData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<String> rightData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private FilteredList<String> leftFilteredData;
private FilteredList<String> rightFilteredData;
```

**This method populates the first list**

This list holds all the values that are going to be used

```
private void loadResultList(){
        if( session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            //Clear list View
            leftList.getItems().clear();

            //Get entity node
            HibernateUtil hibernateUtil = new HibernateUtil();
            //Get query results
            List resultSet = hibernateUtil.executeSQLQuery(session, selectedEntity.getValue().get("query").asText());

            //Wrap resultset into Observable list
            resultSet.forEach(result -> leftData.add(((Map)result).get("NAME").toString()));

            // 1. Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
            leftFilteredData = new FilteredList<>(leftData, p -> true);

            // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
            wrapListAndAddFiltering(leftFilter, leftFilteredData);

            leftList.setItems(leftFilteredData);
            leftList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        } else{
            Alert noDBCon = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            noDBCon.setTitle("No Database connection");
            noDBCon.setHeaderText("No Database Connection");
            noDBCon.setContentText("Select and connect to a DB before doing any transaction.");
            noDBCon.showAndWait();
        }
    }

private void wrapListAndAddFiltering(JFXTextField filterField,FilteredList<String> filteredData) {
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(item -> {
            String filter = filterField.getText().toLowerCase();
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            if (item.toLowerCase().contains(filter)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

**Methods to add and remove elements**

```
@FXML
private void addItemToList(){
    //1.- Add elements to right list
    //Wrap left elements into Observable list
    leftList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(item -> rightData.add(item.toString()));

    //Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
    rightFilteredData = new FilteredList<>(rightData, p -> true);
    wrapListAndAddFiltering(rightFilter, rightFilteredData);
    rightList.setItems(rightFilteredData);

    //2.- Remove elements from left list
    leftData.removeAll(leftList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    leftFilteredData = new FilteredList<>(leftData, p -> true);
    wrapListAndAddFiltering( leftFilter, leftFilteredData );
    leftList.setItems(leftFilteredData);
}

@FXML
private void removeItemFromList(){
    //1.-add elements to left list
    rightList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(item -> leftData.add(item.toString()));
    leftFilteredData = new FilteredList<>(leftData, p -> true);
    wrapListAndAddFiltering(leftFilter, leftFilteredData);
    leftList.setItems(leftFilteredData);

    //1.-Remove items from right list
    ObservableList<String> temp = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    rightList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(el -> temp.add(el.toString()));
    //rightList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(rightData::remove);
    rightData.removeAll(temp);
    //rightData.removeAll();
    rightFilteredData = new FilteredList<>(rightData, p -> true);
    wrapListAndAddFiltering( rightFilter, rightFilteredData );
    rightList.setItems(rightFilteredData);
}
```

**The GUI**

[image]

Comment: Are you double-clicking or drag-and-dropping to move elements?

Comment: @Sedrick no, i'm selecting (multi select enabled) and the using a button to add or remove the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Comments in the code. It shows how to set up the `FilteredList` and how to move data from one `ListView` to another.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication239 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private ListView lvLeft, lvRight;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfLeft, tfRight;

    ObservableList<String> leftData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<String> rightData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    FilteredList<String> filteredLeftData, filteredRightData;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        leftData.addAll(getFakeDataFromDB());//get data from DB
        //rightData.addAll(getFakeDataFromDB());//Used for testing
        filteredLeftData = new FilteredList(leftData, s -> true);
        filteredRightData = new FilteredList(rightData, s -> true);

        //Set filtered Lists
        tfLeft.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == null || newValue.length() == 0) {
                filteredLeftData.setPredicate(null);
            }
            else {
                filteredLeftData.setPredicate(t -> {
                    return t.toUpperCase().startsWith(newValue.toUpperCase());
                });
            }
        });

        tfRight.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == null || newValue.length() == 0) {
                filteredRightData.setPredicate(null);
            }
            else {
                filteredRightData.setPredicate(t -> {
                    return t.toUpperCase().startsWith(newValue.toUpperCase());
                });
            }
        });

        //Set listview items
        lvLeft.setItems(filteredLeftData);
        lvRight.setItems(filteredRightData);

        //Set selecton model selection mode
        lvLeft.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        lvRight.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnActionMoveToLeft(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {        
        List<String> itemsToMove = new ArrayList(lvRight.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());//If you don't do this "new ArrayList(..):", then  you need to first addAll then removeAll
        System.out.println("list size: " + itemsToMove.size());
        rightData.removeAll(itemsToMove);
        leftData.addAll(itemsToMove);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnActionMoveToRight(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        List<String> itemsToMove = new ArrayList(lvLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());//If you don't do this "new ArrayList(..):", then  you need to first addAll then removeAll
        System.out.println("list size: " + itemsToMove.size());
        leftData.removeAll(itemsToMove);
        rightData.addAll(itemsToMove);
    }

    List<String> getFakeDataFromDB()
    {
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList();
        tempList.add("Hello");
        tempList.add("Hello World!");
        tempList.add("Bye");
        tempList.add("Bye World!");
        tempList.add("Been");
        tempList.add("Bad");

        return tempList;
    }

}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication239.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="lvLeft" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label text="Left" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfLeft" />
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="5.0">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnActionMoveToRight" text="Move To Right" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnActionMoveToLeft" text="Move To Left" />
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
            </VBox>
            <Label text="Right" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfRight" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <ListView fx:id="lvRight" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Thanks you this worked. I'm still unsure why my method failed but I will check it later.